# Why isn't this Jquery keypad working when I use a master page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Click [here](http://keith-wood.name/keypad.html) for the source of the jquery keypad.

I have used this keypad in my project at a separate form and it works but whenever I use the same thing in another form with a master page it doesn't work. In my master page all off he necessary references are added (same references are also added in the head part of the form just in case!)

```
<script src="../App_Themes/Default/js/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<%--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>--%>

<script src="../App_Themes/Default/js/jquery.keypad.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#txtFTP').keypad();

});
</script>
```

Even if I delete my masterpage reference of the same form and I replace my content place holders with HTML tags the jquery keyboard works.

Can anyone suggest me why isn't it working?

**UPDATE 1**

To test more about this problem I have created a new test masterpage. The code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestMasterPage.master.cs" 

 Inherits="Member_TestMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org

/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <title>Untitled Page</title>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see that there is no reference in the master page for jquery.

Then I created a new test.aspx page. The code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Member/TestMasterPage.master" 

AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="2.aspx.cs" Inherits="_2" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
 <script src="../App_Themes/Default/js/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"> 
 </script>

 <script src="../App_Themes/Default/js/jquery.keypad.js" type="text/javascript">
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
$('#txtFTP').keypad();

   });
 </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
 <div>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtFTP" SkinID="Mini" runat="server" TextMode="Password"   
  ForeColor="Gray" />
 </div>
</form>

</asp:Content>
```

But the jquery keyboard doesn't work. But if I remove the master page reference and change the page accordingly the keyboard works! The code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="2.aspx.cs" Inherits="_2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org 
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>

<script src="../App_Themes/Default/js/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../App_Themes/Default/js/jquery.keypad.js" type="text/javascript">  
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#txtFTP').keypad();

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFTP" SkinID="Mini" runat="server" TextMode="Password"  
ForeColor="Gray" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**What am I doing wrong? Why can't I make it work with a master page?**

Answer (score 2):

Your scripts src paths won't always work. They will work only when your page is in a folder inside your root folder, but not if you're in the root already or more deeply.

The master page mechanism makes the problem more complex. If you don't use a master page, then it is not hard to see if your links would work or not. You just have to see if your page path is OK with src value, for example here it would work if your page is in one folder. However, when you come to master page, your links will work relatively to the page, not to the master page, so when you write your master page you don't know anything about where you are in the tree.

The solution for that is to specify the link from the root with the help of the server like that:

```
<script runat="server" src="~/App_Themes/Default/js/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(Your "App_Themes" folder should be in the root folder)

Comment: the form and the master page are in the same folder. I used "~" but this did not fix the problem. It doesn't work even if i put all the references for the keypad in my form's header content place holder instead in the master page.

Comment: You need to debug the javascript and see why it is not working.